# Как сделать пользователей кто он-лайн?

Tags: php

Нужно сделать, чтобы в окошко кто он-лайн выводились пользователи, которые действительно он-лайн. Можно ли это сделать так:

```
<?
include 'lib_1.php3';
if (isset($restore) != 1) {
    $restore = "yes";
}
if ($restore != "no") {
    copy("nicks_in.cht", "nicks_now.cht");
    $kill_nicks = fopen("nicks_in.cht", "w");
    fputs($kill_nicks, "<b>Смотритель</b>#");
    fclose($kill_nicks);
    $nicks_fle = file("nicks_now.cht");
    make_array($nicks_fle[0], "#");
} else {
    $nicks_fle = file("nicks_in.cht");
    make_array($nicks_fle[0], "#");
}
?>

<?
$chatters = 0;
while ($chatters != count($resault_array)) {
    echo $resault_array[$chatters], "<br>";
    $chatters++;
}
?>

<html>
<style>
<head>
background-color: #9999FF ;
</style>
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><p>На этой локации: </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p><?
include 'lib_1.php3';
if (isset($restore) != 1) {
    $restore = "yes";
}
if ($restore != "no") {
    copy("nicks_in.cht", "nicks_now.cht");
    $kill_nicks = fopen("nicks_in.cht", "w");
    fputs($kill_nicks, "<b>Смотритель</b>#");
    fclose($kill_nicks);
    $nicks_fle = file("nicks_now.cht");
    make_array($nicks_fle[0], "#");
} else {
    $nicks_fle = file("nicks_in.cht");
    make_array($nicks_fle[0], "#");
}
?>

<?
$chatters = 0;
while ($chatters != count($resault_array)) {
    echo $resault_array[$chatters], "<br>";
    $chatters++;
}
?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно извратиться и сделать на ajax ... <br>Тут какой то не красивый код <br> я боюсь его 

Comment: Если-бы вы использовали отступы в коде - шансы на ответ возросли-бы многократно...<br>
P.S. Примите старые вопросы!

Comment: danial72 а как в личку написать?

Comment: @danial72 имел введу в асю как я понял

Comment: Собственно интересно зачем делать на ajax? это чат?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку)))